# Content security policy error while loading apex iframe

Tags: iframe, salesforce, content-security-policy, salesforce-lightning

Issue: We get CSP (Content Security Policy) error with our Visualforce page integration.

The issue is that when we access this in sandbox testing, we find that our content is wrapped in an iframe, and that iframe also contains an iframe.

The outer iframe does not seem to have a URL, and so we cannot exclude it from our CSP whitelist.

apex putting the iframe dynamically inside another iframe that is not having any src, that is why we are not able to whitelist the domain that can open our site into iframe.

- This is the sample parent iframe.

```
<iframe allow="geolocation *; microphone *; camera *" frameborder="no" height="1000px" id="0661b0000004nmw" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" name="0661b0000004nmw" scrolling="yes" title="HelloWorld" width="100%">
  <iframe src="https://example.com"> </iframe>
</iframe>
```

- Error log from developer console of browser.

```
[Report Only] Refused to display 'https://example.com' in a frame because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors 'self' *.salesforce.com".
```

Please let me know if there is a way to resolve the content security error in this case!